# Fuel Dataset Import Error

Tags: python

When i am importing fuel.datasets.hdf5. I am getting below error. Does anyone know the solution?

---

```
ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call    last)
<ipython-input-23-9cbd4ef5a9e4> in <module>()
----> 1 from fuel.datasets.hdf5 import H5PYDataset
  2 from fuel.schemes import ShuffledScheme, SequentialScheme
  3 from fuel.streams import DataStream
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fuel.datasets'

Comment: How you installed fuel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this 
sudo apt-get install libhdf5
sudo pip install h5py 
and then import module 
1. import h5py
2. from fuel.datasets.hdf5 import H5PYDataset
3. from fuel.schemes import ShuffledScheme, SequentialScheme
4. from fuel.streams import DataStream